# How would you go about creating a facade like this? How do I make each element unique and texture them so it looks hyper-realistic in the end?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, workflow

I want to create a wooden facade like this, with many elements, too many for each one to be created manually. I am wondering how to automate the "distortion" of the mesh when I array them, and also how to make this distortion look like wood. Also, do you have any texturing tips that would make it hyper-realistic?

[image: The facade][1]]

Comment: You can follow any tut for wooden floor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikNnhaPGjiI that seems to me as similar technique

Comment: Hello, (not the down voter) but I think this kind of question is not really suited for this site. Hyper realistic is really opinion based. For instance I don't consider your example to be hyper realistic, in reality the pieces of wood forming the house's plating wouldn't have the same length. I don't think the knots in the wood suit the width of the wood pieces. I'd expect this kind of wood pieces to deform along their longest axis, here they are almost perfectly straight. Unless coated in dye they would also accumulate moss on the top part and along the ground, etc.

Comment: My point is photorealism can't be achieved with one single technique. You must break down every part of your model and place it in reality, see how it would interact with the other elements, with the environment, with time, with light, with wild animals, whatever. It's a never ending process of refining progressively smaller details

Comment: what's that thing on the roof though? If that is a real photo I'd rather stay away of that place

Answer (score 2):

The distortion for the wooden planks/Bamboo poles you can create with a *Displacement* modifier with very low strength (`0.005267`). Add it after the *Array* modifier. Use a `Musgrave` texture with low size=`0.03`, type `fBM`. This gives you something like this:

[image]

You need a better wood shader than in this example so that the poles/planks don't look like "toothpicks".

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from my desktop, so I can't provide example screenshots, but assuming you have a high enough resolution copy, have you considered using your picture as the texture, and doing displacement mapping based on the light and darkness in the part of the image with the wood? It's the "lazy" solution, but also one which lets you build this quickly, and with inherently realistic textures since you're using the actual textures.